# how to add custom footer in magento 2

Tags: magento2, footer, footer-links

[image]

I want to add footer link like I attach image .
I am using magento2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in admin go to Content->Blocks and there you will find `footer_links` cms block. You can edit **footer_links** cms block and add layout / html of your footer.

or create a cms block with any name i.e **my_custom_footer** and call this in your theme layout ( Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml ) footer section like :

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-socialmedia-link" after="-">
  <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">my_custom_footer</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: I think it’s worth mentioning that in a clean Magento install, there are no blocks in the CMS whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add extra link

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link-1">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My new footer title</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path-link</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

#### Add block to you footer

If you want to add different links with Titles etc, you have to create a new phtml then add your links with `<ul> <li> etc...`

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="my-new-footer" as="footer.new" label="Page new Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-footer" template="html/custom-footer.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom-footer.phtml

Footer content here

Answer (score 0):

To add footer links in your Magento 2 store, create  a layout file default.xml. Let's suppose you have to add **Create account** link, for that here's a code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
       <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-footer-link">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Create Account</argument>
                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/create/</argument>
             </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```